# Running php project in xampp by a single click

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to make a file/script (like maybe an icon) as to run a php project with single click on my localhost. I am on Windows OS and been using XAMPP. Also the project has a MySQL database. An .exe file would have been great but I tried "EXEOUTPUT FOR PHP 1.7" but it cannot connect with my MySQL database.

So I thought can a SCRIPT/FILE be made which can start my Xampp, Apache server, MySQL and then automatically run my project which is in htdocs folder.

Comment: i need same what you want because some clients need local project but they doesn't know or want to start xammp and then go on!!!

Comment: For me "EXEOUTPUT FOR PHP 1.7" was doing the trick. But I am unable to understand the documentation that they gave in their site so cannot make the database connection work. Other than that everything was awesome. Even the animations were working

Comment: i already done that by setting xammp_start.exe in windows startup program and then i sett up my local project link by default when chrome is open

Comment: bookmarked or make it as primary link, auto startup the XAMP server

Comment: write a `bat` file with your `URl` and whenever double click the `bat` file browser will open with exact `URL`. e.g for `start chrome https://www.google.co.in/`. Then We can not change the `ICON` for `BAT` files. but we can create `SHOTCUT LINK` for `BAT` file also change the ICON.may be this one help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have create a .bat file which allows user run program

create test.bat file (for windows) and paste below code

```
@echo off
    cd "D:\xampp\" //your xammp path
    start xampp_start.exe
    TIMEOUT 10 //set timeout until xampp control fully start
    cd "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application" //your chrome path
    start chrome.exe 127.0.0.1\myProjectName   //your url
    exit
```

**Before Executing file please remove all comments**

**ALSO HAVE TO KEEP THE BATCH FILE IN THE SAME DRIVE AS XAMPP**

Comment: @Vishnu: I have put the test.bat file in the desktop. My XAMPP folder is in E-Drive. So I have made the changes like "E:\XAMPP\". But it is not getting the path. Chrome and URL is working fine. But not the XAMPP part. Any idea?

Comment: No. nothing of that sort. Let me paste my code below:

@echo off
    cd "E:\XAMPP\" 
    start xampp_start.exe
    TIMEOUT 10 
    cd "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\" 
    start firefox.exe http:\\localhost\my_project   
    exit

Comment: @Roger Before Executing file please remove all comments

Comment: Did that too... even tried to run the bat files of APACHE and MYSQL. But it shows it cannot get the path. Is it because i kept the TEST.BAT file in desktop?

Comment: yes if your put original file on desktop it will not find the drive path instead of that put somewhere .bat file in drive and send its shortcut  to desktop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121989/discussion-between-vishnu-bhadoriya-and-roger).

Answer (score 1):

I have made a batch file which will allow to open the web based app using XAMPP which required one click you can also modify the shortcut using custom icon that explanation is available in my blog which can read with full modifications.

This is the sample batch code just modify the location and project name.

```
@echo off

tasklist /fi "imagename eq xampp-control.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "xampp-control.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    echo XAMPP control panel is already running
    TASKKILL /F /IM xampp-control.exe
) else (
    echo XAMPP close
)

rem Check for Aapavhe
netstat -ano | find ":80" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo Apache running,Stop it
    TASKKILL /F /IM apache.exe
) else (
    echo Apache running
)

rem Check if MySQL running 
netstat -ano | find ":3306" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo MySQL is already running
    TASKKILL /F /IM mysqld.exe
) else (
    echo MySQL stopped
)

rem Start the XAMPP
start "" "C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe"
rem Open the project URL in the browser
start "" "http://localhost/projectname"

rem Add a delay of 3 sec
timeout /T 3

rem Close the prompt
start /B exit
```

Check for Explanation: [Here](https://noobstep101.blogspot.com/2023/01/how-to-start-xampp-and-localhost.html) On my blog for more description.